# Session, cookies and Security

Tags: .net, cookies, session-cookies

I got a problem.

I have a web app,where I do the following:

1)Login
2)later extract the cookie
3)Logout
4)Insert manually the cookie

and when I visit some page again, I'm logged. How can I fix it? I want the cookie expiration.

thanks for your response.

Comment: What does your code look like when you are logging the user out? Are you setting an expiration date on the cookie?

Comment: No, the cookie expire when the session does.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the built-in Forms Authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

What is in that cookie? Just a "loggedin = yes" value?

In that case you could change that to "loggedinsession = {current session ID}".

On logout, delete the cookie (set the value to empty, without expiry) and also [.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) the session (so a new request gets a new session ID).

The logged-in check then changes from "does the cookie exist" to "is the value the same as the current session ID".

Comment: localhost FALSE / FALSE .ASPXAUTH AB0CE30382A679E7C57832E944B1969EC3CAF4E7DE42108...

Comment: I want to destroy the session in server side, for protect the user when logout

Comment: @Tarlak - See the Session.Abandon() method (see edited link in answer)